# What is the mail server to use for connecting to Hotmail?

Tags: email

I tried to connect to `Gmail` successfully using (after allowing `Less secure app access` in `Gmail`):

```
server=MailServerConnect[
    "imap.gmail.com",
    MailSettings-><|
        "Username"->"xxx@gmail.com",
        "Password"->"xxx",
        "PortNumber"->Automatic
    |>
]
```

And have been able to manage it from Mathematica but can't get it to connect to my `Hotmail` account.

```
server=MailServerConnect[
    "imap.xxx.com",
    MailSettings-><|
        "Username"->"xxx@hotmail.com",
        "Password"->"xxx",
        "PortNumber"->Automatic
    |>
]
```

Does anyone know the server URL to use for connecting to `Hotmail` and any additional steps?

---

Ok, I looked into my account and got the following settings:

> POP setting: Server name: outlook.office365.com Port: 995 Encryption
>   method: TLS
>
> IMAP setting: Server name: outlook.office365.com Port: 993 Encryption
>   method: TLS
>
> SMTP setting: Server name: smtp.office365.com Port: 587 Encryption
>   method: STARTTLS

So I updated my commands and got a failed still:

```
server=MailServerConnect[
    "outlook.office365.com",
    MailSettings-><|
        "Username"->"xxx@hotmail.com",
        "Password"->"xxx",
        "PortNumber"->993,
        "EncryptionProtocol"->"TLS"
    |>
];
folder=server["Inbox"];
item=folder[-1]
```

> $Failed

What am I doing wrong?

---

Tried and logged in successfully via Outlook desktop application using the following settings:

> IMAP setting: Server name: outlook.office365.com Port: 143 Encryption
>   method: TLS

So tried to replicate these settings in Mathematica and got the following error message:

```
server=MailServerConnect[
    "outlook.office365.com",
    MailSettings-><|
        "Username"->"xxx@hotmail.com",
        "Password"->"xxx",
        "PortNumber"->143,
        "EncryptionProtocol"->"TLS"
    |>
]
```

> MailServerConnect::auth: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext
>   failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the
>   function is invalid
>
> $Failed

Comment: try `imap-mail.outlook.com` as a server URL

Comment: Same `$Failed` not working with this server URL as well.